# how to get head of the list after traversal in Linked lists?

Tags: c++, c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have traversed a linked list and ended up reaching NULL in head in between I modified some elements in head. How do I get back the head pointer with those modifications.

```
Node* temp=head;
while(head&&head->next){
    head=head->next->next;
}
```

I want linked list to be modified into new one with alternate nodes. So after this how can I get back the new head pointer.

EDIT:

```
ListNode* temp=head,*new1=head;
        while(head!=NULL&&head->next){
            new1->next=head->next->next;
            head->next=head->next->next;
            new1=new1->next;
        }
        //temp=head;
        return new1;
```

Comment: The answers can only be as good as the question. Posting a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would definitely improve the question.

Comment: Simply use the temporary node to perform traverse rather than the head so that head is left unchanged

Comment: I want it to be modified in that list itself

Comment: What do you expect the `while` loop to do for you? How can you check that it did the right thing? You can often answer your own questions if you think about what code you can add to double check that what you intended to happen actually did happen.

Comment: The while loop adds alternate nodes of head to new node.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a different pointer to traverse the list, and leave `head` alone.

Another way is to restore `head` after you are done. Your code seems to indicate this is possible, since you have stored `head` in `temp` before you entered the loop.

```
head = temp;
new1 = temp;
```

Comment: But head or temp(traversed one) will be NULL after completion of loop. How can I get starting pointer back?

Comment: I showed you. Assign the right value back to the variable.

Comment: But the modification done to the linked list that is skip alternate nodes is not done it gives the same linked list.

Comment: I don't understand how your complaint about it giving the same linked list has anything to do with the question as asked.

Comment: I want the new linked list to contain alternate elements. How can I get its head pointer?

Comment: How about you try to write a program that takes nodes out of one list and adds them to a different list?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you meant to do is:

```
Node* temp = head;

while(temp && temp->next){
    temp = temp->next->next;
}
```

That way, you always have the head.

Comment: Ya this is better as the head node is left unchanged +1 vote :)